# Can't create event in default iOS 7 calendar

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
#import <EventKit/EventKit.h>
```

I can't create event in default iOS calendar.

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
for (EKSource *source in eventStore.sources)
{
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV || source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)
    {
        NSLog(@"I found it");
        break;
    }
}
```

Beginning from here it couldn't return any sources. When I build and run app there are no any requests to give its access to default calendar.

All in all I get an empty array:

```
[eventStore.sources count]
```

Even when I trying to add event without creating new calendar (using

```
[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]
```

Comment: have you get permission for events?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess there is problem in accessing EKEventStore, to check permission try following,

```
 EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]){    
   [eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
         {
             NSLog(@"GRANTED: %c", granted);
             for (EKSource *source in eventStore.sources)
             {
                 if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV || source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)
                 {
                     NSLog(@"I found it");
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }];

}
```

Hope it Helps you..

Comment: You should not check the system version, but wether or not the method is available: `if ([eventStore respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)]){`

Answer (score 2):

I have found problem:

```
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    // TODO
}];
```

I must request permission manually, thought permission set without it, I think it had fixed in iOS 7.0.2 build.